# "Join" between two tables is very fast versus "Left join" which is extremely slow (MySQL DB)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables (about 300,000 rows each table) with one column identifier column (ID) that is indexed. The following query takes a few seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

Versus the following query which takes hours:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a LEFT JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

The difference between the two queries is that one is done with a "join" and one with a "left join".

The query result need to include all the rows from Table_1 so I have no choice but to perform a "left join".

Also tried this approach which also took allot of time as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID

UNION

SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a LEFT JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
WHERE b.ID is null;
```

Any suggestions??

Thanks allot in advance...

Comment: How long does it take to all from Table_1?

Comment: I have a feeling you have shown us a 'simplified' version.  Please provide the actual `SELECT`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information provided, I can only think of trying something like this:

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.column1, b.column2, ..., column(n)
FROM Table_1 a JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID

UNION

SELECT a.*, '' AS column1, '' AS column2, ..., '' as column(n)
FROM Table_1 a 
WHERE a.ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT a.ID FROM Table_1 a JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID);
```

**Edit:** I wanted to clarify why this is faster and make this a more complete answer.

This is because of the plan followed by the server to achieve the desired results.
A left outer join such as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a LEFT JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

It has to go through every record in Table_1 weather it matches something in Table_2 or not. And, as the table grows this becomes more and more expensive.

By adding `WHERE b.ID is null` it basically has to go through a non-indexed column to filter the result of the previous operation. And, it has to create those nulls first in order to perform this, so it will likely not create a more optimal plan.

```sql
SELECT a.ID 
FROM Table_1 a 
JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

The inner join takes advantage of a better algorithm. And, it we're making use of indexed values not in a list. This perform better compared to its counterpart as the table increases in size and requires more operations. But, we could receive some performance hits later as the inner join return a larger number of indexes to filter by.

Since I there was no further context provided, or clearer use case. I think the solution is sufficient. But, it could be improved upon given a better understanding of the full problem.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN is equivalent to INNER JOIN, so the first query will return rows *only* where the IDs match. The index here helps performance too.

Your second query performs a LEFT JOIN, which as you pointed out returns everything from table A, regardless if it matches something in table B.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need 300,000 records of possibly unindexed data.  There are really only two things that you can do to help speed things up.  Number one, put an index on your tables on the id column.  Number two, only select the columns you need, rather than selecting everything.  For example:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.dat1, b.dat3
FROM Table_1 a LEFT JOIN Table_2 b on a.ID=b.ID
```

This will reduce the amount of data being processed.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_1 a LEFT JOIN
     Table_2 b
     on a.ID = b.ID;
```

You want an index on `table_2(id)`.  If you don't have an index on `Table_2` that starts with `id`, I would expect the performance to be very bad.

An inner join can take advantage of an index on either table.  For a `left join`, and index on the second table is more important.